# Getting the (rearrenged) order of html table rows as request parameter

Tags: java, request, submit, forms, tablerow

I have a html table inside a form that I want to submit.

```
<table border="1" id="sort_table" >
```

The table contains 6 rows, and I have already written a javascript program that allows the user to rearrange the order of table rows.

I know I can get the state of a checkbox, etc... in the java code from the Request object like this:

```
String checkboxPara = req.getParameter("checkbox_id");
```

But how can I get the parameters of a table? (Assuming maybe there I can find a hint for the new orders of the tablerows).

None of the lines below work, both return null.

```
String [] tableParamS = req.getParameterValues("sort_table");
String tablePara = req.getParameter("sort_table");
```

Any idea is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put a **hidden** input field in each tablerow with ***the same name*** like this:

```
<input type="text" name="order" value="start" hidden="true" />
```

and from the java code the parameters are accessible like this:

```
String [] s= req.getParameterValues("order");
```